# Ubuntu 12.04: C++ Program -> Broken Pipe -> Cannot get past Tty1

Tags: boot, nvidia, tty, console, pipe

While I was running a C++ program (it involved SDL), the computer completely froze up; control C didn't work, and escape didn't work (I had it programmed that escape would close the program). So, after a lot of mashing, I reset the computer. That was when I encountered a "could not write bytes: Broken Pipe" error. Since I couldn't really move on from there, I restarted again, and this time I was prompted to a tty1 console. I had an nvidia card, and I encountered this tty1 console loop before, so I purged my nvidia drivers and reinstalled. However, this didn't work either, and then after restarting again, my tty1 console constantly pops up. Not only that, but the console will transition to a black screen with a blinking cursor after like 30 or so seconds. All of this because of the C++ program.

If it helps, I also noticed that I no longer have an nvidia module or nv module (in xorg).

Things that happened before I ran that program: I downloaded clang, llvm, and libsdlv1.2. I also did an update manager thing.

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks